# Call Generic EventHandler from generic class

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, event-handling

I am faction and problem with the below implementation, Compiler throwing error "delegate has invalid argument error by compiler" , check below code for this

```
public class MessageArgument<T> : EventArgs
{
    public T Message { get;  set; }

    public MessageArgument(T message)
    {
        Message = message;
    }
}

public class Publisher<T>
{
    //Defined datapublisher event
    public event EventHandler<MessageArgument<T>> DataPublisher;

    public virtual void OnDataPublisher<T>(MessageArgument<T> args)
    {
        var handler = DataPublisher;
        if (handler != null)
         //delegate has invalid argument error by compiler
            handler(this, args);
    }

    public void PublishData<T>()
    {
       //also facing issue with creating of generic type instace
        MessageArgument<T> message = (MessageArgument<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MessageArgument<T>), new object[] { 10 }); 
        OnDataPublisher(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: `DataPublisher` has no idea, whether `T` in `OnDataPublisher<T>()` is variant to the `T` in `MessageArgument<T>`

Comment: I guess, you have to set some restrictions on `T` through `where` clause so the type system can infer the variance. This might be a helpful read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx

Comment: Aren't you getting any warnings before the error you're asking about? I ask because I do get warnings, and those warnings already hint at what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a generic class, this means that you do not need generic constraints on the method, as they are treated as a separate generic type. Remove the `<T>` constraint from your methods and it should be working:

```
public class Publisher<T>
{
    //Defined datapublisher event
    public event EventHandler<MessageArgument<T>> DataPublisher;

    public virtual void OnDataPublisher(MessageArgument<T> args)
    {
        var handler = DataPublisher;
        if (handler != null)
         //delegate has invalid argument error by compiler
            handler(this, args);
    }

    public void PublishData()
    {
        MessageArgument<T> message = (MessageArgument<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MessageArgument<T>), new object[] { 10 }); 
        OnDataPublisher(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution worked for me ...thank you...actully <T> was not there before but i got some error and to resolve that i put <T> but now there is no error is coming